# Fix Position DIV not Overlapping content

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue getting my fixed position navigation menu to overlap my text, a example of this is: http://www.saveur.com/michel-roux-scrambled-eggs-with-asparagus-and-crab-recipe

With the code I have currently managed the fixed position navigation appears behind the text, but I want it to be at the top and overlapping at all times, just like the website above.

All of the content is fixed position, I have made this so that if any one could help me they could just edit the code easier.

HTML: http://pastebin.com/j7jHjb4h

CSS: http://pastebin.com/sWuLChut

How can I make it so that the navigation menu stays at the top even when scrolling down just like the website above.

Comment: This is the HTML: http://pastebin.com/j7jHjb4h

Comment: you could use z-index to the menu and give it a highest number ex z-index:99999;

Comment: Who's voting everything down here? ffs

Answer (score 0):

Just add a z-index value to the fixed element:

```
z-index:100;
```

If larger than any other z-index on the same level, it will overlap everything as needed.

Comment: I don't appreciate my correct answers being marked down - it's not a competition, it's about making sure we solve problems!

Comment: Upvoted. Even SO isn't immune to Kindergarten warfare.

Comment: so why do I get downvoted as well then if you say it's not a competition

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me out and it works thank you guys

Answer (score -1):

```
#navMenu {
   margin:0;
   width:200px;
   height: 1px;
   z-index: 1000;
}
```

You could try to give it a high z-index